# Reverse Fatou Lemma with uniform boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X_T)$ be a positive sequence of random variable such that $\mathbb{E}(X_T)=1$ for all $T$. Under which condition can we state that:
$$
\mathbb{E}(\limsup X_T) = 1
$$
Would uniform boundedness be enough for example?
Fatou Lemma gives the inequality $\geq$, what remains to see is the other inequality.

Comment: Do you want to assume that $X_T\ge 0$? Otherwise I am not sure how you may apply Fatou's Lemma

Comment: Uniform boundedness does suffice though, as does the weaker of uniform integrability $\limsup_{m\to \infty}\sup_{T} \mathbb{E}[|X_T|I(|X_T|>m)]=0$. For more information you should look around the Vitali convergence theorem.